# Why intruder number of threads has an effect on the time delay of indiviual requests

Tags: sql-injection, burp-suite, postgresql

I was solving SQL injection [lab](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/blind/lab-time-delays-info-retrieval) on Portswigger, and the lab was asking to exploit blind SQL injection by triggering time delays, using that to retrieve administrator password.

I was making 720 requests by Burp intruder, to test `(a-z, 0-9)` payload on each position of password whose length was 20. If my condition is true, ex. `substring(password, 15, 1) = 'g')` , then make a `2000 ms` delay by executing `pg_sleep(2)`.

The solution of the lab mention that you will need to make these requests using only one thread instead of 5 (the default). That's my question, why number of threads matters here, I think it will matter if we are calculating the whole delay of all requests, but it will not matter on the delay of the 5th request for example.

If the request take `100 ms`, and the number of threads was 5 or 1, the delay of this request alone will not change.

The point is, I made it with 5 threads to see how it will work, but I found that the requests that have a `subtring(password, 20, 1) = 'q'` and `substring(password, 20, 1) = 'c'`, both have a delay exceeds `2000 ms`, although it was supposed to have only one of them is exceeding 2000ms, as only one of them is true and pass the condition and execute pg_sleep(2).

Can someone explain to me why number of threads matters here?

**Edit:**
I'm talking about synchronously processing of the requests, not asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

when doing blind timed SQL injection, timing is everything!

if you do this multi-threaded, you need to take care that thread switching does not interfere with your timing attack (both on your client as on the server).
since you have no control over how the server is implemented or how it handles treading, the default advise for any blind SQL injection based on time is to have only 1 tread of it running.

E.A. using multi-threads makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot with false positives / negatives.

Comment: OK, I understand why it's better to make 1 thread, because you don't how the server is implemented or how it handles the threading, But this advise is about the whole attack time, isn't it?  the main point that confused me, why this affecting the delay of an individual request! if a specific request takes `100 ms`, and the server is implemented in the way x, and handles threads in the way y, let's said finally thread 3 takes the control, and starts that request, once it takes the control, it should take `100 ms` in that request, isn't it?

Comment: Or you mean that maybe thread switching for example affecting the time the request takes itself? not the whole time attack?  @LvB

Comment: As soon as you leave the machine, you no longer can be sure about what will affect timing how. for example, even if your test is that a positive is a delay of 1000ms vs 100ms . if your query had to wait for a additional 900ms you get a false positive. hammering the server with request (something you easily do multi-threaded). especially if your not the only user of a system at that time.